# Hide link in Listview on Lookupfield

Tags: custom, list, lookup-column

In my customList there are several lookups. They link to the sourcelists.
My question is:
How can I hide these links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are creating a custom list schema, you can do what you want with two fields:

```
<Field 
    ID="{AB09A2D6-AE91-EBD4-4511-A8C54DC8442F}" 
    Type="Lookup" 
    Name="MyLookup" 
    DisplayName="Lookup" 
    List="$Resources:core,lists_Folder;/Source" 
    ShowField="Title" 
    Hidden="FALSE" 
    Required="TRUE" 
    StaticName="MyLookup"
    ShowInDisplayForm="FALSE" />
<Field 
    ID="{E558933C-85C9-A03B-4932-6A786396AA78}" 
    Type="Lookup" 
    Name="MyLookupDisplay" 
    DisplayName="Lookup" 
    List="$Resources:core,lists_Folder;/Source" 
    ShowField="Title" 
    Hidden="FALSE" 
    JoinColName="tp_ID" 
    JoinRowOrdinal="0" 
    JoinType="INNER" 
    FieldRef="MyLookup" 
    ReadOnly="FALSE" 
    ShowInNewForm="FALSE" 
    ShowInEditForm="FALSE" />
```

Comment: Sounds great, but where can I find this list schema?

Comment: I prefer to create it using Visual Studio. But if you are creating the list in the browser, you can go to List Settings > Save list as template. Check out these links for instructions on extracting (plus editing and repackaging) the XML: http://tom-dw.blogspot.com/2010/06/importing-sharepoint-2007-list.html and http://nanddeepnachan.blogspot.com/2009/11/sharepoint-export-list-retain-lookup.html

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I know a way to solve the "problem". I thought this would be easier changing it somewhere in the webinterface. 
I'll try to save it as a template and modify it now.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a calculated field based upon the lookup field, that would display the value of that field, without the link.

Comment: When I try to add a calculated value based on one of these columns to the list, the columns I need to hide the links in don't appear in the "Insert Column"-Box. So I can't generate a calculated value based on them.